# General error 1114 when querying a table only 4% of the storage capacity in an RDS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have the following problem when attempting to draw stats on a table located in an Amazon AWS instance.

The table is composed of a huge list of names, dates and state two letter codes among other things. The dates are represented by a 6 digit code where the first four digits are the year and the last two digits the month (yes, we don't care about the day).

I do a query to check the table size and it returns: 4097 MB which sounds about right.

But I also need to run the following query:

```
SELECT state_code,COUNT(date_code) as cnt,date_code
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE (date_code > 200801) 
    GROUP BY date_code,state_code
    ORDER BY  state_code ASC
```

Basically I want to know how many rows I have have for each date_code on each state.

My RDS instance is a db.m4.large running MySQL 8.0.23 with 1000 GiB of storage and a Maximum of 2000 GiB

I get this error: Failed getting the number of obits by year and state. Reason: Select failure: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table '/rdsdbdata/tmp/#sql7245_5bc3_1' is full.

Now, there is a question very much like this one here: How to solve MySQL “The table is full” error 1114 with Amazon RDS?

However the solution is to simply increase the storage size, but 4 GB is only 4 % of the storage size. And this table will be ever increasing.

How could I solve this issue? Is the only answer to increase table size

Just FYI, this will be a very seldom query. Worst case scenario something like once a day. I need for it to work, no really interested in making it fast. In case it matters.

Comment: What are the values of `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` system variables?

Comment: @TasosP. - Those should not be more than about 1% of RAM, which might not be enough to be worth using.

Comment: @TasosP. I have no Idea where to check this on RDS, could you tell me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  state_code,
        COUNT(*) as cnt,   -- assuming `date_code` is never NULL
        date_code
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE (date_code > 200801) 
    GROUP BY  state_code, date_code   -- note swap
    ORDER BY  state_code, date_code   -- matching GROUP BY
```

Add `INDEX(date_code, state_code)`.

Notes:

- `COUNT(*)` is the normal syntax for counting; `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being not null before counting.
- The ordering in `GROUP BY` is probably not important, but is in `ORDER BY`.  Since you asked to order by `state_code`, I changed `GROUP BY`.  Then, ...
- When `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are the same, there is no need for a second sort.
- The new index is "covering", so it will scan the index in it rather than scanning the bulkier data BTree.

If the "older" data is never changing, you can get a much faster query by building and maintaining a "summary table".  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: Hi Rick Thanks for the answer. Ironically I don't really need a sort so I gor rid of it. I only care about the grouping. I replaced the the COUNT(date_code) with the COUNT(*) and understood the add INDEX(date_code,state_code) to be an ALTER TABLE Query. After that, the query work. Thank you so much.

Comment: `GROUP BY` by itself _usually_ sorts.  But it may not always.